# External IP addresses logged as "Martian source" on Docker interface

Tags: openvpn, docker

I am running OpenVPN in a container ([kylemanna/docker-openvpn](https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn)) on Ubuntu 15.10 and Docker 1.13.1.

On the host, in `/var/log/syslog` I am getting quite a number of the following messages:

```
Apr  4 19:35:32 v1 kernel: [10364441.158397] IPv4: martian source 151.101.1.69 from 192.168.255.6, on dev docker0
Apr  4 19:35:32 v1 kernel: [10364441.158440] IPv4: martian source 151.101.1.69 from 192.168.255.6, on dev docker0
Apr  4 19:35:32 v1 kernel: [10364441.158467] IPv4: martian source 151.101.1.69 from 192.168.255.6, on dev docker0
Apr  4 19:35:32 v1 kernel: [10364441.158492] IPv4: martian source 151.101.1.69 from 192.168.255.6, on dev docker0
```

Where `192.168.255.6` is an OpenVPN client address and `151.101.1.69` is a legitimate site I try to access from the remote client.

Not all accesses are logged this way, but a significant number of them.

I understand that in a regular setup only special addresses are logged as "Martian packets", here however these are regular internet-deliverable IP addresses.

I also understand that the setup Docker+OpenVPN might be non-trivial from the point of view the kernel, however I am still confused with my actual logs.

- What is the reason for these packets to be logged as Martian?
- Are they dropped or logged only?
- Is there anything to fix in the configuration (either to correct if the configuration is wrong or just to prevent the messages from being logged if it's expected)?

Comment: `192.168.255.6` _is_ a special address, so if the host doesn't know about it, that is a Martian packet. How does your client obtain its IP? How are its packets routed?

Comment: "*How does your client obtain its IP?*" --> OpenVPN does that. "*How are its packets routed?*" --> Not sure, what can I answer here.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10 is EOL. I don't know if that could be related to your problem at all, but you should definitely upgrade!